# Can't add users to SharePoint site - Cross Domain causing an issue?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, access-denied, trusted-domain

The user can view the site, they simply always receive "ERROR: Access Denied". The error message also picks up their domain\user as expected.

I am using SharePoint 2010.

The SharePoint server is in another domain than the user however there is a trust relationship between the two. My user, is also in the same domain as the other and I can access the site as expected.

I have checked, the user is a member of two SharePoint groups within the site however they have no other permissions. I have tried it on a few users and they all have the same problem.

I believe the problem is something to do with SharePoint not being able to accept users from the domain, I just don't know where to start looking anymore?

Comment: I have been testing various combinations, I can grant user access by applying the permissions within central administration directly for the user.  Unfortunately that is unacceptable.  I have since removed the user from Central Admin, the main portal and checked they don't exist.  I have then ensured they only have permissions on the sub-site - they do (and check permissions returns this as expected).  The user still gets "Permission Denied".  I am at a loss, I am investigating Domain Trust just now as whilst my user works I have some elevated permissions between domains (apparently).

Comment: I've seen quirky things like this where there is some other asset (e.g. an image) that is somewhere else in the collection or such and the user gets "access denied" to the entire page. Suggest looking at the traffic with fiddler or equivalent from their browser to see exactly what URLs they hit on that page and then make sure their account has at least read access to all.

Comment: I am wondering something else now - It turns out the SharePoint site is a Project SharePoint site and I am wondering if the user needs permissions on MS Project Server as well?  Unfortunately I know little about Project Server and how it integrates with SharePoint